# Open PDF in MediaWiki

Tags: pdf, mediawiki, wiki

In my mediawiki, I can link to internal PDFs using:

```
[[File:test.pdf]]
```

But if the user clicks the link, a single page for this file is opened like:

```
http://localhost/mediawiki/index.php/File:test.pdf
```

How can I achieve, that the PDF file is opened directly with no other pages in between needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Media:` pseudonamespace to link directly to the file:

```
[[Media:Test.pdf]]
```

This will link to:

```
http://localhost/wikimedia/images/d/d3/Test.pdf
```

The (slight) documentation about this is at: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Links#file-links